# Removing simple whitespace c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I read in the contents of a file i then search for this string

`00:00:00" group="MAM` and remove it !.

This is the full line that the string is on

```
 <Field name="original_transmission_date" value="20/01/1969 00:00:00" group="MAM" />
```

so after I string.replace it ends up .

```
 <Field name="original_transmission_date" value="20/01/1969 " />
```

My problem is that little space you see between the 9 and the " , trying to think of ways to get at it, the values and date will change but I could regex from value= onwards but I am not great with regex and it seems over kill for a whitespace!.

Any Ideas?.

Comment: How are you currently removing it?  Show that code.

Comment: Is the space always there? Why not just include the space in the original search string?

Comment: The cheeky way would be to shove an extra space in front of the pattern you're searching for...

Comment: why do you remove the time stamp? why not simply use `Date.ParseExact` to parse the entire field when you post back in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replace string should also contain the space, ie  `" 00:00:00\" group=\"MAM"`

Answer (score 3):

You question is a little fuzzy and may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Are you retrieving this data or setting this data?  Is this XML?  Most likely there is a better solution not using REGEX at all.

Worst case scenario what not just do something simple like:

`.Replace(" 00:00:00\" group=\"MAM", "").Replace("00:00:00\" group=\"MAM", "")`.

Comment: +1. Doing string manipulation on XML file is bad for your karma. @user685590, please consider proper XML APIs for that.

Comment: "XY Problem", i have to rememeber that link ;)

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix if the group is always the last tag:

Replace [00:00:00" group="MAM" /] with /

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.trim to remove white space , also you can use string.TrimEnd

```
            char[] charsToTrim = { ' ' };//here you can any character to trim
            myString = myString.TrimEnd(charsToTrim);
```